# django form dropdown list of numbers

Tags: python, django, linux

i am new to django and i want to make a simple form, according to the doc i can make a form using forms module from django

```
from django import forms

class CronForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False, label='Your e-mail address')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        num_words = len(message.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
        return message
```

what i want to know is how to create a dropdown list of days in month i.e from 1 to 31?

some have done it using javascript in their form template, can this be done in django?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're looking for a `ChoiceField` which renders as a `select` html element by default.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

```
class CronForm(forms.Form):
    days = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)])
```

Comment: cool that worked, is it possible to add one more value at the start of the list, something like ("*","Every").

Comment: Sure, just add it to the list :)  `choices = [("*", "Every")] + [(x, x) for x in range(1, 32)]`

Comment: Just as an alternative, if you initialize your field in models with a tuple argument `choices`, as `models.CharField(choices=list_of_choices)`, and `list_of_choices` being a tuple containing your choices, you could also turn your field into a dropdown-list-aware field. doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 0):

you can start by choosing to render the fields manualy.
A simple example:-

```
{% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

This will render the form without any styling then you have to apply the relevent class to create a drop down list(copied from w3c dropdown css):-

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

combining the two :-

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Days
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                {% for field in form %}
                    <li class="fieldWrapper">
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```