# Django - Create a dropdown list from database

Tags: mysql, django, dropdown

I'm very new to Django and I would like to create a drop down box using distinct value of a column in a database:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class SensorsTable(models.Model):
    sensor_uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    sensor_desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sensor_mid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    gw_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_blg = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_room = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_position = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sensors_table'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sensor_uuid
```

I want a drop down list to contain all distinct values of sensor_loc_room and if the user select a room (sensor_loc_room), table displaying all sensors in the room will be displayed.

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
from django import forms
from .models import *


class LocationChoiceField(forms.ModelForm):
    #locations= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=InputLocation.objects.all())
    locations = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SensorsTable.objects.all().values_list("sensor_loc_blg").distinct())
```

This is my current view.py (only use to display a table of all sensors):

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


from .models import *


#def index(request):
#    return HttpResponse("Smart Uni Analytics Test")


def index(request):
    query_results = SensorsTable.objects.all()
    locationForm = LocationChoiceField()

    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,

    }
    return render(request,'analytics/index.html', context)
```

And index.html(only use to display a table of all sensors):

```
<table>

    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_uuid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_desc }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_mid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.gw_uuid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_blg }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_room }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_position }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: maybe i'm just really tired but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055808/django-form-dropdown-list-of-stored-models) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to create a drop down box using distinct values from a column in a model. In case someone is looking for an answer:

models.py:

```
class SensorsTable(models.Model):
    sensor_uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    sensor_desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sensor_mid = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    gw_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_long = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_blg = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_room = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor_loc_position = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'sensors_table'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sensor_uuid
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import *


class LocationChoiceField(forms.Form):

    locations = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=SensorsTable.objects.values_list("sensor_loc_blg", flat=True).distinct(),
        empty_label=None
    )
```

views.py (most simple way)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import *

from .models import *



def index(request):
    query_results = SensorsTable.objects.all()
    location_list = LocationChoiceField()

    context = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'location_list': location_list,

    }
    return render(request,'analytics/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<body>

<div class="container">
    <p></p>
    <form method=POST action="">
        {{ location_list }}
    </form>



    <h1>All sensors</h1>
    <table>

        {% for item in query_results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_uuid }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_desc }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_mid }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.gw_uuid }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_blg }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_room }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.sensor_loc_position }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```