# Django Forms- drop down menu of from model 'id' received from URL

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, dropdown

I want to make drop down menu of id from all data that is stored in the model. Later I want to pass that id to my views.py to populate my form to update. How do i go about this?

I know that I need some form field and view for that but I don't know how to do it. I am new at Django so this is relative strange to me. Any help would be extremely useful.

models.py -

```
class TVchannel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name of program")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Type of program")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Channel state")
    price = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], verbose_name="Price of channel")

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name<code>
```

views.py - view for update

```
def userUP(request, user_id):
#instance = get_object_or_404(TVchannel, id=user_id)
queryset = TVchannel.objects.filter(id=user_id)
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = TVchannelUpdateForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        updateIt = TVchannel.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = TVchannelUpdateForm(request.POST, instance = updateIt)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

else:
    updateIt = TVchannel.objects.get(pk = id)
    form = TVchannelUpdateForm(insance = updateIt)

return render_to_response('app/updateTVchannel.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))<code>
```

forms.py - form for update

```
class TVchannelUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = TVchannel
         fields = ['name', 'type', 'state', 'price]
```

Answer (score 0):

[django form dropdown list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859504/django-form-dropdown-list-of-numbers)

^ Check this answer out, just populate the list with the data from the id from the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's not problem. I don't know how to make form of dropdown menu and fill it with id of data. I suppose that I have to do some form and view maybe, but I don't know how to do that.